# htaccess to use links without index.php5

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is what I am trying to achieve:
I have written my own little CMS and want it to work with links not containing "index.php5", e.g. www.website.com/blue instead of www.website.com/index.php5/blue.
The links are stored in a database. Now I am trying to figure out what I have to do in order to use these links. Trying it with index.php5 included works, but if I set up my CMS to create links without index.php5 I get a 500 error.

This is how my .htaccess looks when working with index.php5 turned on:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
DirectoryIndex index.php5
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.website.com/index.php5/error404
```

To work with links not containing index.php5 I tried to change it into this, but then I end up with the 500 error.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
DirectoryIndex index.php5
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.website.com/error404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php5?/$1
```

I also tried to find answers here, but obviously I did not yet figure out how to change the .htaccess into something that is fitting my needs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php5/$1 [L]
```